# undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state) But added bind(this) in my method call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

On my application, I added a Touchable Opacity, when I click on that i need to run a function.

```
<TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        style={styles.Button}
        onPress={this.login_account.bind(this)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When I try to this.setState inside that function it throw a warning
[image]

What did I wrong in this?

This is my login_account function

```
login_account() {
    let username = this.state.username;
    let password = this.state.password;

    error_message = "";
    has_error = false;
    if (username == "" || password == "") {
      error_message += "Username and password should no be empty.";
    }
    if (has_error == false) {

      //code here....

    } else {
      this.setState({
        status_code: 6001,
        message: error_message,
        show_popup: true
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you defining ```this.state```?

Comment: "this" probably refers to the render method at this point. Try binding this in the constructor

Comment: @Epitouille, not if OP is using ES6 classes, which judging by the presence of `state` I assume OP is.

Comment: you are right @ethane! thanks for the precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the `this` you're binding the function to isn't the one for the Component, depending on where that code is.

Try either binding in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.login_account = this.login_account.bind(this);
}
```

Or turning the `login_account` method into an arrow function so it doesn't override `this`:

```
login_account = () => {
    ...
};
```

Comment: let username = this.state.username;
let password = this.state.password;
These two values are available When I try to console.warn() these values it appears correctly. But when I try to setState It shows the same error. I tried both the methods

Comment: If you do `console.warn(this.setState);` inside of the `login_account` method what does it give you?

Comment: Now I found the error , that I missed to set a variable has_error to true for rendering that code block. But now I'm facing the same error within the error block of axios post request

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement your function as an arrow function, then you don't need to bind it anymore:

so, you function will looks like:

```
login_account = () => {
   // your code here

}
```

and modify function property in your Touchable components to be just like:

```
<TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        style={styles.Button}
        onPress={this.login_account}
      >
        <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```